# How do I select entire table of data one row at a time?

Tags: php, sql, select, row

I have a table (customer) with 10,000 records. I would like to modify every single record one at a time and modify some data then update it back into the database. It doesn't make sense to SELECT * FROM customer then fetchAll since there are 10,000 records.

I'd like to create a while loop in PHP which does a incrementing SELECT statement but what would a select statment like this look like if there is no stable primary key that increments nicely? Logically the while loop would look like:

```
$row = 1;
while(Number_Rows_In_Table)
{
  $record = $this->db->exec("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ROW = $row");
  $row++;
  //Do something with the data then update it
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It'll be much faster to select all the records initially.

Comment: Do you *really* have to loop through all the records? Could you explain what you are doing - there may be a way to do it with one SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use fetchAll you know:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Do stuff with specific rows one a time
}
```

This **will** be much faster than having 10,000 select queries. I can guarantee you that.

Comment: +1 For saying what I tried to say but better and with code :)

Comment: @nickb: Didn't see you there!

Comment: I am decrypting and encrypting entire tables one record at at time. I think this will work. I was afriad of doing a SELECT * since there was so much data. I guess the data doesn't actually get pulled until you do the fetch so I think this will work.

Comment: @Vidarious: No, `fetch` will automatically advance one row in the resultset each time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use offset, limit syntax available in MySQL... but it seems like a strange thing to do

```
SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT $row, 1
```

Assuming `$row` starts at 0 and is auto-incremented (like in your example). You'd probably have to order it as well.

Comment: I think you have the limit arguments backwards ^^

Comment: @SamDufel Wouldn't be the first or last time :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `fetchAll()` and grab all of the rows, just fetch one row at a time from a `SELECT * FROM customer` query with [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to update you can probably just use SQL. For example, to find and replace a sting:

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```